# Simultaneously assign same value to multiple places?

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to assign to two (or more) variables, e.g., `x` and `y` (`z` etc.) the same value read from user input.  Now I have `(setf x (read))`, but I'd like to also have the input value put in `y` as well. Do I have to then do `(setf y x)`?  Is there something more elegant?

```
(setf x (read) y (read))
```

only makes the user input twice, so that's no good.

Comment: How about `(setf x (setf y (setf z (read))))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing quite like that built into the language, though you can easily implement it.  E.g., here's a macro **setf*** (not the best name, though), that assigns a single value to a bunch of places (which don't have to be variables):

```
(defmacro setf* ((&rest places) value)
  (let ((temp (gensym)))
    `(let ((,temp ,value))
       (setf ,@(mapcan (lambda (place)
                         (list place temp))
                       places)))))
```

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(setf* (a (car list) (aref array 2 3)) d))
(LET ((#:G1043 D))
  (SETF A #:G1043
        (CAR LIST) #:G1043
        (AREF ARRAY 2 3) #:G1043))
```

You'd do

```
(setf* (x y) (read))
```

Of course, for a simple one off, you might as well just do this by hand, as either (as sds suggested):

```
(setf x (read)
      y x)
```

or

```
(let ((temp (read)))
  (setf x temp
        y temp))
```

Comment: minor improvements: give the gensym a string (something like "value" or similar). Helps reading the expanded code. Also a good idea is to check that places is actually a list. Most macros should do some syntax check.

Comment: @RainerJoswig With a declaration of `(defmacro setf* ((&rest places) value)`, could places be anything but a list?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was actually thinking how to make it check that it is a *meaningful* list of places. For example how to get it detect a missing level of parentheses like in `(setf* (aref a b) 42)` ... somehow...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, that would be useful, though not very practically possible.  After all, `aref`, `a`, and `b` can all be variables;  maybe someone wants to set them all to the same value.

Answer (score 3):

you can assign `x` to `y` in the same form:

```
(setf x (read) y x)
```